# Style Imported Custom Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So I'm importing a custom component `TextButton` and packaging it inside of another `OutlinedButton`. I export the class `OutlinedButton` expecting to see both the props passed and the new styling added to be rendered. However, only the props are being correctly rendered. The extra styling that I added does not appear at all. Any thoughts as to why this occurs?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TextButton from './TextButton';
class OutlinedButton extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <TextButton {...this.props} style={styles.outlineButtonStyle} />
        );
    }
}

const styles = {
    outlineButtonStyle: {
        borderWidth: 1
    }
};

export default OutlinedButton;
```

TextButton class (it's a bit long)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class TextButton extends Component {    
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {};
    }

    componentWillMount() {}

    componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
        if (newProps.theme !== this.props.theme) {
            this.determineTheme(newProps.theme);
        }
        if (newProps.size !== this.props.size) {
            this.determineSize(newProps.size);
        }
    }

    // set the theme
    determineTheme = function (theme) {
        if (theme === 'primary') {
            return {
                color: '#0098EE'
            };
        } else if (theme === 'secondary') {
            return {
                color: '#E70050'
            };
        } else if (theme === 'default') {
            return {
                color: '#E0E0E0'
            };
        } 

        return {
            color: '#E0E0E0'
        };
    }

    // set the size
    determineSize = function (size) {
        if (size === 'small') {
            return {
                fontSize: 16
            };
        } else if (size === 'medium') {
            return {
                fontSize: 22
            };
        } else if (size === 'large') {
            return {
                fontSize: 28
            };
        }

        return {
            fontSize: 22
        };
    }

    render() {
        const { onPress, children, theme, size } = this.props;

        return (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
                <Text style={[this.determineTheme(theme), this.determineSize(size)]}>{children}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    }
}

TextButton.propTypes = {
    onPress: PropTypes.func,
    title: PropTypes.string,
    theme: PropTypes.string,
    size: PropTypes.string
};

export default TextButton;
```

Comment: Could you show your `TextButton` component as well? I suspect the issue is in that component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the `style` prop passed down to your `TextButton` component:

```
render() {
  const { onPress, children, theme, size, style } = this.props;

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} style={style}>
      <Text style={[this.determineTheme(theme), this.determineSize(size)]}>{children}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This fixed the problem! I'll remember to pass down style next time.

Comment: @yesar Great! It happens to the best of us. Welcome to stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

When you set style as below in `<TextButton>` Component, you are not setting the style on the component, but passing it as props to the component. So you have to access it in `<TextButton>` as this.props.style and apply it in the child component as Tholl mentioned below. Hope you got it.

```
 render() {
        return (
            <TextButton {...this.props} style={styles.outlineButtonStyle} />
        );
    }
}

const styles = {
    outlineButtonStyle: {
        borderWidth: 1
    }
};
```

SImple example: https://codesandbox.io/s/wn9455x58